# adding new JButton() with actionListener without declaring it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I wanted to add a JButton with actionListener to a JPanel without declaring the JButton like below.

```
JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
tempPanel.add(new JButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
   }));
```

Error message gives me `Cannot resolve method 'add(void)'`.

I am not sure why this is incorrect. Is it just a grammar error? or is it not possible for me to add JButton with ActionListener like this?

I know for sure, it would work if I do like this.

```
JButton tempButton = new JButton();
tempButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    });
tempPanel.add(tempButton);
```

I will appreciate your help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: because `addActionListener` is the method you invoke on the `JButton`, and the method doesn´t return a `JButton`, since it´s `void`. In the end `void` isn´t a valid parameter for the `add` method. You can´t chain methods like that in `Java` normally, since they most likely don´t return `this`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
so, does that meaning there's is no different ways to make my first code work? except the way that I have written as second code?

Comment: new JButton(new AbstractAction() { ... }) you need to implement the actionPerformed method within AbstractAction, but you'll get basically the same result

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you! You always answer questions well, including several others of mine and a ton of others... I always see you answer or comment on Java questions... Thanks again! :) `</offtopic>`

Answer (score 2):

`JButton#addActionListener` returns `void`, been the last call in the chain, it's the result that the compiler will try to send to `JPanel#add`, which, obviously, makes no sense.

While I won't argue the merits of method chaining, the API is the way it is.

You could do something like...

```
JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
tempPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
}));
```

instead, which would result in the same thing as you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Java give you the error message because the `tempPanel.add()` takes the return value of `addActionListener()`, which is void.

Some libraries do provide chained function(eg. Dialog in android) which you can write code like this. But, I'm afraid, in this case, you have to declare it first and then add a listener for the JButton. Or, you could try to write your own Button class which extends JButton, and you can add a parameter as listener in its constructor.